# ClassCastException thrown on Component.getInstance(GateAction.class, true)

Tags: java, resteasy, jboss-seam

I am new in Seam. I am using Rest services and in one of my rest service I am trying to get Instance by Component like,

```
GateAction gateAction = (GateAction) Component.getInstance(GateAction.class, true);
```

So with this I got error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No application context active

then to resolve this I call Lifecycle.beginCall() and Lifecycle.endCall() methods as below,

```
Lifecycle.beginCall(); 
GateActionIntf gateAction = (GateActionIntf) Component.getInstance(GateActionImpl.class, true); 
Lifecycle.endCall();
```

where GateActionIntf is an Interface and GateActionImpl is seam component which implements GateActionIntf. But now I am getting ClassCastException.

**Note** : In my web service project I don't have any component.xml and seams based configuration, I have just added jboss-seam jar

Is that possible to get instance like that, without any component.xml and seams configuration? Again just highlighting I am getting the Instance but while type casting throws ClassCastException. how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
GateActionIntf gateAction = (GateActionImpl) Component.getInstance(GateActionImpl.class, true);
```